# What is rebinning of data?

Tags: statistics

Let's say we have a set of data with relative flux as a function of wavelength. How does one perform rebinning of the data?

Comment: Flux compensator? Sorry, very new to this.

Comment: there is a statistics site http://stats.stackexchange.com/